# Ubuntu Budgie HotCorners Problem

Tags: budgie, applet, ubuntu-budgie

Can someone please help me to figure out how to fix this problem:
I have installed HotCorners Applet along with Previews and Window Shuffler.
But whenever I choose Corner Actions like Toggle Shuffler GUI, Exposé all windows or Exposé current application I get this message - Missing process Please enable Window Previews or Window Shuffler.
My Ubuntu Budgie Version 21.10 and GNOME Version 40.4.0.
I tried reinstalling applets but to no avail. Googling yielded the following solution [[20.04] hot corners do not work](https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/20-04-hot-corners-do-not-work/4400/19). Unfortunately setting pressure to 0 didn't solve the problem.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hello. I see you are having issues with theses add on applets. Do they not have their own support? You are aware that 20.04 is using a version 3 Gnome not 4 so it may not work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Enabling Hotcorners to use Shuffler and Previews

To use Shuffler and Previews, you need their daemons to run. If you set Hotcorners to use their functionality, it checks if that is the case, and warns you if not.

Activating is done simply by their respective control centers, accessible via main (application) menu.

**Window Shuffler:**

Tick at least one of it's features to make its daemon start up.

[image]

**Previews:**

[image]

**N.B.** Shuffler and Previews are no applets, but mini-apps!

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for the hint! Run Previews box was unchecked indeed. The problem with Exposé all windows and Exposé current application is solved. Window Shuffler Control feature was ticked initially (like on your screenshot). However, setting Toggle Shuffler GUI action still gives an error message.

Comment: @PavelSchriber, never mind, I tested it, indeed only with toggle gui the warning is false, that's a bug! Will fix. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @PavelSchriber Reopened: https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/budgie-extras/issues/363